# gedit syntax highlighting for assembler files (*.asm)

Tags: linux, assembly, syntax-highlighting, gedit

By default, gedit doesn't syntax highlight `.asm` files.

How can I add this support for this language?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The following steps should be enough.

```
wget http://www.carminebenedetto.net/_downloads/asm-intel.lang
sudo cp asm-intel.lang /usr/share/gtksourceview-3.0/language-specs/
```

Note that the exact folder to copy the `.lang` file to depends upon your version. You may have `gtksourceview-2.0` instead, or even something else. On my machine I had both 2.0 and 3.0, and copied the file into each one's `language-specs` subfolder.

Comment: It looks like there's [a newer version of this file](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GtkSourceView/LanguageDefinitions?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=asm-intel.lang) in the [the gtksourceview list of additional languages.](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Projects/GtkSourceView/LanguageDefinitions)

Comment: there is also https://github.com/cdclaxton/gedit-assembly-language-syntax-highlighter

Answer (score 9):

Apparently the language definition provided on the [extra language definitions page](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GtkSourceView/LanguageDefinitions) is not working with `gtksourceview-4.0` 
I changed the file a bit and it works for me. The updated version can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/mrbesher/5c98da1c220d10e2aba8276554d3456c).
Also here is a [version](https://gist.github.com/mrbesher/79d3d43a657fc73e5b0ae5ab98ad3cb6) for the 8086 (I have limited knowledge when it comes to XML and gtksourceview, feedback is welcomed)

Answer (score 1):

I tried the suggested links but to no avail. However the package found in link below worked for me.

https://gist.github.com/mrbesher/5c98da1c220d10e2aba8276554d3456c