# How to syntax highlight different assembly languages in Gedit?

Tags: assembly, syntax-highlighting, gedit, gtksourceview

By default, text editors using GtkSourceView (such as Gedit and Mousepad) don't highlight `.asm` files. The [solution by Drew Noakes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17003402/2738262) is to download a GtkSourceView language definition file for x86 assembly language into `.local/share/gtksourceview-3.0/language-specs/`. I know how to make a language definition file per [GNOME.org's GtkSourceView documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gtksourceview/stable/).

However, I routinely work with multiple instruction sets, each of which needs different highlighting rules:

- MOS 6502 assembly (for NES, Commodore 64, Apple II, Atari 8-bit, etc.)
- Sharp SM83 assembly (for Game Boy)
- Zilog Z80 assembly (for MSX, ZX Spectrum, Game Gear, etc.)
- ARM assembly (for Game Boy Advance, etc.)

All of them may use `.s` or `.asm` as a file name suffix, so the `<metadata><property name="globs">*.s</property></metadata>` appears inadequate to distinguish them.

Is there a good way to indicate the instruction set of an assembly language file to a GtkSourceView editor? In particular, is there a better way than locally defining an Internet media type for each ISA using [shared-mime-info](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/shared-mime-info-spec/), using `<magic>`, and ensuring that all collaborators also have the same locally defined Internet media type?

Comment: i think you must switch them manually. I switch between RISCV and ARM every time.